# Setting locale/language while creating D2L user with RestAPI

Tags: desire2learn

We are using Valence API to integrate D2L with our application. Since our application support multiple language how can I pass the users locale/language to D2L LMS. As per my findings I could not find any parameter in createuser object or userprofile object through which I can pass the locale/language informaiton. There is an option for setting the locale while creating the course, however since it is possible that multiple user (of different locale) may use a course and in that case how can I control the content delivery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the current API does not support setting or adjusting the user locale. This gap is a candidate feature for future releases.

In the interim, you could perhaps add a link sent to the users that let them update their locale:

On V10, if you let the user follow a link with the form:

https:///d2l/lp/preferences/preferences_main/preferences_main.d2l?ou=

They will be presented with the page that allows them to set the locale (and they will be prompted to login first if they have no current session).

Comment: Is this fixed in newer versions? Has an api been added?